# Android problem: Custom dialog layout is used instead of main.xml for root activity

Tags: android, customdialog

I was following [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) to make a custom AlertDialog.  I want to make a dialog with buttons and a title like an AlertDialog, but also with an EditText box, which a regular AlertDialog can't use.  So I made the following custom layout containing the EditText box in a file called add_player_dialog.xml in res/layout, which will be called by AlertDialog.Builder's setView():

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/add_player_dialog_layout"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="10dp"
   >
  <EditText
     android:id="@+id/player_name"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the activity (not the root activity, btw) that starts the dialog, I have the following in a switch in onCreateDialog():

```
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_player_dialog,
                   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_player_dialog_layout));

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter player's name")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
        })
    .setView(layout);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

The problem is that the activity that is first used when the application is launched uses add_player_dialog.xml for its layout, not main.xml.  How do I avoid this?

=================

EDIT: I have found a programmatic way to accomplish this, if anyone is interested:

```
import android.R.drawable;

EditText et = new EditText(this);
et.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
et.setBackgroundResource(drawable.editbox_background);
et.setTextSize(20);
```

=================

If you're interested, here is main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="40dip"
   >

  <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     >
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/new_game_button"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/new_game_button"
       />
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/continue_button"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/continue_button"
       />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try/have

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

in the onCreate method?

If so, sorry, hopefully someone else can better chime in.

Comment: Yeah, I have that.

Thank you for your help tho.

Comment: Can you post your main.xml and the activity your talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting gen/R.java and letting the build system regenerate it, I have seen that sometimes when you add IDs it gets out of sync and needs to be forcefully regenerated.